# ERROR in multi main, Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200/' in 'node_modules\angular-cli\ models'

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I Am new in Angular2 Cli, Here I found an errors while running my Cli project.

**ERROR in multi main, Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200/' in 'node_modules\angular-cli\ models'**

I have installed 'webpack' and 'webpack-dev-server' globally, but still the error remain.

Any body, please help me to find a solution.

Thanks,

Comment: I only had to install angular-cli locally and it worked

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to install `webpack` nor `webpack-dev-server` globally. They come installed by CLI.

I had the same issue today. And I discovered that I was using an old shell session that was using Node v4. After upgrading to a newer version of Node (v6). I had no more issue.

Comment: I was using Nodev4.4.7

Comment: can you upgrade to v6?

Comment: Yah wassim I have upgrade that to latest, 6.9.1, but throws some error while I creating new project.

Comment: I'm still having this problem I tried with node7 and node6 but still the same error, has anyone find a solution yet?

Comment: I think its a version problem, I got a new error [ Cannot find module 'broccoli-funnel']  while creating new project.

Comment: I tried node v7.0.0, v6.9.1 and 6.9.0, also angular-cli-1.0.0-beta.18 and angular-cli-1.0.0-beta.19-3 and npm 3.10.9 and npm4.0.1 but still the same error.

Comment: My problem was that I have set npm to install the packages in a legacy bundling way by adding this line to /home/user/.npmrc file: legacy-bundling=true, removing that file and reinstalling everything solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade your node

```
https://nodejs.org/en/
```

Install

```
npm cache clean

npm update -g

npm install -g ember-cli
```

Then delete your old project and run commands  again

```
npm install -g angular-cli

ng new my-new-app

cd my-new-app

ng serve
```

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same error.

node 6.9.0, npm 3.10.8

EDIT:

Solved my problem via [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2891#issuecomment-256347257).

The solution was to install **angular-cli** locally.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was failing not only for `webpack-dev-server` but also couldn't find the application module and `app.component.sccs` (some info about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42592436/angular-2-module-not-found-error-cant-resolve)).

I've tried a lot of options, like the official [Angular setup guide](https://angular.io/guide/setup-local) and ofc the above solutions.

It turned out the issue was a damn simple which ordinary can happen when developing for **Windows**, which was that the **application path was too long**. By moving the project to the drive root folder, all problems were gone.