# Angular 2: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-modules

I have a simple app created with Angular-CLI, I wanted to refactor and move the app.component.ts code in separate component file and started to get a nasty error:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve on './sb/sb.component.html' (
>   my SBComponent).  Under the

This what i have:

app.module:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { SBComponent  } from './sb/sb.component'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent, SBComponent  
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgModule,ElementRef, ViewChild, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent  {


}
```

new component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgModule,ElementRef, ViewChild, AfterViewInit, AfterContentInit} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'


@Component({

    selector: 'app-sb',
    templateUrl: './sb/sb.component.html'
})
export class SBComponent  {



}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `sb.component.html` exist inside sb folder ? if they are both in the same folder then try this `./sb.component.html`

Comment: Yes it exists within the sb folder, app.ts exists outside that folder.

Comment: inside the `SBComponent` change the `templateUrl` to `templateUrl: './sb.component.html'`

Comment: Thank u!  That worked! I gave one vote, does that count as answered?

Comment: no..that just means important comment..to count as answered, someone should add it as answer and @eagleEye needs to accept it

Comment: Thanks @suraj!  @DotNet Dreamer can you please add it as an answer so that I can mark it as answered?

Comment: @eagleEye glad it helped :)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If your component is inside the same directory, then you need to point your `templateUrl` to the same folder as well. Here is how you can do it:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-sb',
    templateUrl: './sb.component.html'
})
```

Answer (score 8):

This problem is very well known, when we are using component relative paths for external html and css files. The problem of absolute path and relative path can be resolved just by adding metadata ModuleId in component.

Now what does ModuleId do? ModuleId contains the absolute URL of the component class **[when the module file is actually loaded]**

*This <kbd>[ModuleId](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/08/component-relative-paths-in-angular-2.html#agreeing-on-constraints)</kbd> value is used by the Angular reflection processes and the metadata_resolver component to evaluate the fully-qualified component path before the component is constructed*

It's very easy to use. Just add one more entry in @Component decorative. Full code example is below.

```
 @Component({
  moduleId: module.id,    // fully resolved filename; defined at module load time
  selector: 'app-sb',
  templateUrl: 'sb.component.html' //Observe this.
})
export class SBComponent  {

}
```

Comment: This is worked for me: @Component({
    moduleId:module.id,
    selector: 'my-demo',
    templateUrl: './input-text-validation.html'
})

Answer (score 6):

My problem was the same as questioned here, my solution was quite different

code that was causing problem:

```
@Component({
    selector : 'app-header',
    templateUrl : './header.component.html',
    styleUrls : ['']
})
```

here by changing :

```
styleUrls : ['']
```

to this:

```
styles : ['']
```

helped me remove module not found error, thought someone might get this error due to this silly mistake, that's why shared my solution

Comment: I was using an in-line template and therefore had to change `templateUrl` to `template` also -- thanks for your answer; found this quickly

Comment: In my case, this issue was also happening along with other problems. I've posted the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74994465/806202

Answer (score 3):

Try to give relative path instead of absolute one.

It will fix the Solution.

Like : `templateUrl = '../employee/employee.html'` in your `component.ts`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, above solutions are excellent and must be used to see if it fixes your issue. But the same error message can be displayed if you have set the Template property. I had the issue when I created the component using ng g c and then it had templateUrl but I was writing some test html inside of templateUrl, thinking it is template. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Something a react developer showed me.
Go to your tsconfig.json and inside the outer curly braces {} where you have all the json options and codes, put this

```
"include": [
    "src/app"
]
//if all your components files are in app, you can do this so as to make importation easy. You can just call the component. It should work for you.
```

from here you can easily use import without much slashes /  and dots. like in my code,

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Injectable, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { products } from "product";
//instead of import { products } from ".../../product"; which will still import but might show error.
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';




@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-list',
  templateUrl: './product-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-list.component.scss'],
  providers:  [
    FormsModule
  ]
})



export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit {

 products = products;


onNotify() {
  window.alert("You will be notified when the product goes on discount")
}

share() {
  window.alert('The Product Has Been Added To Your Cart')
}


  constructor() {

   }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me change `styleUrls : ['']` from

```
@Component({
        selector : 'app-header',
        templateUrl : './header.component.html',
        styleUrls : ['']
    })
```

into `styles: ['']` solve this problem