# ./src/app/component/header.component.ts Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './header.component.html

Tags: angular

when i installed the angular it initailly shown me the  default angular output.but when i created the header component ,its showimg the error like this..please can anyone resolve my pbm..?

i tried the solutions which was given by stackoverflow,but its not working

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
selector: 'app-header',enter code here
templateUrl: `header.component.html
`,
styleUrls: []
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
constructor() {}
ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Comment: Where is your HTML file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42592436/angular-2-module-not-found-error-cant-resolve)

Comment: Did you include it in declarations in your module.ts ?

Answer (score 0):

An Error occurs may be if the path for HTML file is not found.
Change this templateUrl in your code

```
templateUrl: './header.component.html',
```

and add your component to module.ts file

```
declarations: [HeaderComponent]
```

Answer (score 0):

Provide relative path instead of absolute path.

As in if your html is in the same folder

```
templateUrl: `./header.component.html'
```

instead of

```
templateUrl: `header.component.html`
```